# how to run two while loops inside a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

```
interval_sec = 15.0
t_end = time.time() + interval_sec
episode = 0
while True:

    while episode < 3:
        print('Episode %s' % episode)
        episode += 1

    while time.time() < t_end:           
        print("hi")
```

I've tried everything. I tried using a for loop (for episode in range(0,3)), deleting the episode var and even defining the

```
while episode < 3:
    print('Episode %s' % episode)
    episode += 1
```

as a function in the loop.

The expected output I am trying to achieve, in pseudo code, is:

the first nested while loop (while episode < 3:) prints out

```
Episode 0
Episode 1
Episode 2
```

then the second nested while loop prints out "hi" for 15 seconds

and then the first nested while loop should print out

```
Episode 0
Episode 1
Episode 2
```

and then the print "hi" for 15 seconds again and so forth. It should repeat this process forever (hence the while True: loop).

Looking for a fix that I haven't tried. Much appreciated

Comment: You need to move `t_end = time.time() + interval_sec` and `episode = 0` into the outermost `while` loop.

Comment: Also, you should realize that printing "hi" for fifteen seconds will print many, *many* hundreds/thousands of times, right? Did you mean to print it once per second?

Comment: @Linuxios yes, I know that. I am using "hi" just as a test replacement for some other code. Could you suggest a quick edit where it prints once per second so I can confirm if this works fully? Thank you so much :)

Comment: Replace your second while loop with something like: `for _ in range(15): sleep(0.9); print("hi")`.

Comment: Also, your first inner while loop should really be a `for`: `for i in range(3): print("Episode %i" % i)`

Comment: This worked—thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Your counting logic for the first loop is wrong.  Looks at the basic pieces of initialization, test, and increment:

```
episode = 0
while episode < 3:
    ...
    episode += 1
```

This forms the basic counting loop.  The problem is that you separated the pieces, placing them in different logic blocks:

```
episode = 0
while True:       # This is fatal to your counting loop's operation
    while episode < 3:
        ...
        episode += 1
```

Python gives you tools to help with this.  The `for` statement gives you a counting loop in one convenient package:

```
for episode in range(3):
    ....
```

Now it's trivial to keep the loop pieces together.

Note that you have the same problem with the ending time: you need to recompute it for each iteration of the outer `while` loop, so that code should come just after the `while True` statement.